# ImageMagick C api, how to set path of new image

Tags: c, imagemagick

i'm building a c program to merge different number of images and store the result in a new png. I'm not able to set the path of the result image: i can set filename and the image is created correctly and stored in the same directory. How can i set to ImageInfo * the path? is this possible?

thank you everyone

Comment: You can just specify the complete path instead of only the file name.

Comment: hi you mean like this: (void) strcpy(composed_image_info->filename, "/var/www/..../final.png"); ? I tried but it doesn't works!

Comment: You should use image->filename instead.